# Insert logic to avoid record with duplicate name and owner, but allows duplicate name with different record owner

Tags: apex, class, developer

Can somebody help me with the logic on the following:

Account List name is existing, but the ownerid is not existing (Different user)  -> insert ok
Account List name is not existing, but owner id is existing in db -> insert ok

Account List name is existing, owner id is existing (Avoid duplicate record with the same Account List name with the same owner)  -> No insert

Basically, I just want to prevent the record to be inserted if the account list name is duplicate and also the same owner, but if the account list has a match in the database, but it's owner is different, it's should be inserted.

The Actual code is the below:

```
public with sharing class InsertAccountListRec_TEST_cls {
    List < User > usersIdList;
    Set < Id > usersIdSet = new Set < Id > ();
    Set < Id > AffFromAcctSet = new Set < Id > ();
    Set < Id > xAcctListOidSet = new Set < Id > ();
    Set < String > xAcctListNameSet = new Set < String > ();
    List < Affiliation_vod__c > allAffParentRecs = new List < Affiliation_vod__c > ();
    List < Account_List_vod__c > newAccListRecList = new List < Account_List_vod__c > ();
    List < Account_List_vod__c > xAcctListRecs = new List < Account_List_vod__c > ();
    List < Account_List_vod__c > InsertedAccList = new List < Account_List_vod__c > ();
    //Creation a list of all Parent Affiliation Records, then add to allParentRecsSet (SET).
    //Start of 1st Block
    public InsertAccountListRec_TEST_cls() {
            allAffParentRecs = new List < Affiliation_vod__c > ([SELECT Id, OwnerId, From_Account_vod__c, From_Account_Value__c, To_Account_vod__c
                FROM Affiliation_vod__c
                WHERE(From_Account_vod__r.Id = '0011200001GNrb0AAD'
                    AND Parent_vod__c = True)
                AND OwnerId IN: getActiveUsers()
            ]);
            System.debug('Parent Affiliation Record Count ' + allAffParentRecs.size());
            for (Account_List_vod__c xAcctListRecs: [Select OwnerId, Name FROM Account_List_vod__c
                    WHERE Name LIKE 'HO_%'
                    AND OwnerId IN: getActiveUsers()
                ]) {
                xAcctListOidSet.add(xAcctListRecs.OwnerId);
                xAcctListNameSet.add(xAcctListRecs.Name);
            }
            System.debug('Account List Record Count ' + xAcctListRecs);
            for (Affiliation_vod__c allParentAffRecs: allAffParentRecs) {
                if (!AffFromAcctSet.contains(allParentAffRecs.From_Account_vod__c)) {
                    Account_List_vod__c AccListRec = new Account_List_vod__c();
                    AccListRec.Name = 'HO_' + allParentAffRecs.From_Account_Value__c;
                    AccListRec.Icon_Name_vod__c = '0';
                    AccListRec.OwnerId = allParentAffRecs.OwnerId;
                    AffFromAcctSet.add(allParentAffRecs.From_Account_vod__c);
                    newAccListRecList.add(AccListRec);
                }
            }

************************************************
            for (Account_List_vod__c acctListToCreate: newAccListRecList) {
                if (xAcctListNameSet.contains(acctListToCreate.Name) && !xAcctListOidSet.contains(acctListToCreate.OwnerId)) {
                    InsertedAccList.add(acctListToCreate);
                }
            }
************************************************

            insert InsertedAccList;
            System.debug('New Account List Records: ' + InsertedAccList);
        } //end of 1st block
    public Set < Id > getActiveUsers() {
        usersIdList = new List < User > ([SELECT Id
            FROM User
            WHERE(Profile_Name_vod__c LIKE '%Eisai_Epilepsy%'
               OR Profile_Name_vod__c LIKE '%Eisai_PrimaryCare%')
              AND IsActive = TRUE
        ]);
        for (User users: usersIdList) {
            usersIdSet.add(users.Id);
        }
        return usersIdSet;
    }
} // End of Class
```

The lines surrounded with asterisks are the current logic which seems incorrect.

Comment: You may want to adjust the formatting used to highlight some lines of your code, bold formatting will only show up as `** bolded **`. I'd suggest moving it into its own code section.

Comment: You might find an answer already on the exchange here: [How to create SQL like composite key](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/109071/how-to-create-sql-like-composite-key/109073#109073).

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want without any code.

---

**Field Setup**

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Objects`.
2. Click on `Account List`.
3. Under **`Custom Fields & Relationships`** click the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
4. Select `Data Type` of `Text`.
5. Populate `Field Label`. Example might be `Unique Owner & Name`.
6. Length should be enough to accommodate and Id (max 18) and a Name (max 40) so 58.
7. Make sure the field is `Unique Case-Insensitive`.
8. Save the field with whatever parameters you wish in the next two screens.

---

**Field Update Setup**

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Field Updates`.
2. Click the <kbd>New Field Update</kbd> button.
3. Populate `Name` with (for example) `Populate Unique Owner & Name`.
4. Select `Object` > `Account List`
5. Select `Field to Update` > `Unique Owner & Name`.
6. Under `Text Options`, select `Use a formula to set the new value`.
7. Fill in `OwnerId & Name`.

---

**Workflow Rule Setup**

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Workflow Rules`.
2. Click the <kbd>New Rule</kbd> button.
3. Select `Object` > `Account List`.
4. Populate `Rule Name` with (for example) `Populate_Unique_Key`.
5. Select `Evaluate the rule when a record is:` > `created, and every time it's edited`.
6. Select `Rule Criteria` > `formula evaluates to true`.
7. Use a formula of `TRUE`.
8. Click the <kbd>Save and Next</kbd> button.
9. Click the <kbd>Add Workflow Action V</kbd> dropdown.
10. Select `Select Existing Action`.
11. Select `Choose Action Type` > `Field Update`.
12. Find your update from above.
13. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
14. Click the <kbd>Done</kbd> button.
15. Click the <kbd>Activate</kbd> button.

Comment: Hi Adrian, the suggestion that you posted is unclear on my end. The creation of Account List record depends on the Parent affiliation record.

Comment: You just want a combination of two fields to be unique, no?

Comment: Yes, but when the Account List is existing but it has different owner, it should be inserted. Example: Account List name: Ho_Account | Owner: Marion (existing record) now, when  the class tried to create an Account List  with name Ho_Account and the owner is not Marion, it should be inserted. But, if the name is Ho_Account | Owner: Marion - it will not be inserted. The class should allow to insert a record which both Account List Name and Owner is not existing.

Comment: This solution accommodates that... did you try it?

Comment: No not yet. I am not sure on how to do it or i'm confused with the steps.

Comment: Adrian, Thank you. But let me clarify, the only time an Account List will be created is when the class determine that there is an Affiliation record with Parent is True and Business Type is Group Practice Account. I am not sure where to stop in apex class and follow the steps that you provide. Or, I should totally stop in apex class and just follow your steps.

Comment: On the Fiedl update set up, no. 7. Is that concatination of Owner Id and Account List name fields?

Comment: @Noiram The two fields you want to be unique. Yes that's what's in my post.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but I need the class first. this isn't working.. Any advise?

Comment: You don't need any `Apex`...

Comment: I need because it should be an automate process, once the class determine an Affiliation parent record, it should create an Account List.